# Section of the projection map

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, string-theory

I have a CY four-fold as a hypersurface of degree $(4,3)$ in $P^3\times P^2$ and I have the projection map from this hypersurface say $X$ to $P^3$ as $\pi:X \rightarrow P^3$. Does this admit a section?

This has some application in String theory to certain instanton corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. By Lefschetz hyperplane theorem the Picard group of $X$ is generated by the pullbacks of the hyperplane classes of $\mathbb{P}^3$ and $\mathbb{P}^2$; this implies that the degree over $\mathbb{P}^3$ of every divisor on $X$ is divisible by 3. But if a projection to $\mathbb{P}^3$ has a section (even a rational section), it is a divisor of degree 1 over $\mathbb{P}^3$.

Comment: Thanks. But can you elaborate the last part

Comment: What precisely?

Comment: Why the divisor be of degree 1 iff there is a section?

Comment: Because the projection from the section to $\mathbb{P}^3$ is an isomorphism (by definition of section), hence has degree 1.